# Pipe expression destination `string.empty` is not a valid function

Tags: sxa, scriban

I'm trying to do something like `{{ "" | string.empty }}` and get `Pipe expression destination 'string.empty' is not a valid function`

I can see it is available here though https://github.com/scriban/scriban/blob/master/doc/builtins.md#stringempty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of Scriban that ships with SXA 9.3, 10.0 and 10.1 is 2.0.1 so you only have the functions available on that version of the doc site - https://github.com/scriban/scriban/blob/v2.0.1/doc/builtins.md